# What is [0] and (1) in: r = np.random.randint((1), 24000, 1)[0]

Tags: python, numpy

What is `[0]` and `(1)` in: `r = np.random.randint((1), 24000, 1)[0]`

Entire github code:

https://github.com/Pawandeep-prog/facial-emotion-detection-webapp/blob/main/facial-detection.py#L230

Comment: [doc](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.randint.html) what wasn't clear?

Comment: That's some awkward code - `r = np.random.randint(1, 24000)` would do the same thing, plus it looks like they probably expected `numpy.random.randint` to include the high end of the range (which it doesn't).

Comment: @DeadPool if any of the answers given helped you, please consider *accepting* one of them. BTW take [*the tour*](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) as to learn how to successfully interact with the SO community :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Deciphering

The [`numpy.random.randint`](https://numpy.org/doc/1.16/reference/generated/numpy.random.randn.html#numpy.random.randn) function returns an array of random integers *if* called with the optional `size` parameter (the third parameter). The low bound (first parameter), `1` in the given case, is enclosed in parentheses without any need but giving part of the confusion.

The following code would generate a one-element array of random integers, in other words, just one random integer, in the range `[1,24000)` (a value which is greater or equal to 1 and less than 24000):

```
import numpy as np

np.random.randint(1, 24000, 1)
```

As we know from basic Python, we access array elements by index in square brackets `[]` whereas the first element is indicated by `[0]`. In the given case, this is also the *only* element.

#### Clarification

To get an integer instead of an array, the `numpy.random.randint` function provides the option to leave out the `size` parameter. That's why the code in question should better be rewritten to <sup>*</sup>

```
np.random.randint(1, 24000)
```

---

<sup>*</sup>
as kindly commented by [*user2357112 supports Monica*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67432532/what-is-0-and-1-in-r-np-random-randint1-24000-10/67432837#comment119190022_67432532).

Answer (score 1):

Here `np` is `numpy`,

`(1)` denotes the minimum value of output

```
np.random.randint((1), 24000, 1)
```

returns an array, so `[0]` denotes the first element of array

for more info check https://numpy.org/doc/1.16/reference/generated/numpy.random.randint.html#numpy.random.randint